# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'cat'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I want to append a list to a tensor, similiar to list.append().

```
flat_models = torch.tensor([])
for model in models:
  flat_model = get_flat_model(layers,model)
  flat_models.cat((flat_models,torch.tensor(flat_model)))
```

flat_model is a 1-dimensional list, containing Tensors. e.g. `[Tensor(1),Tensor(2)]`

Why do i receive the error? how can  append the list to my tensor?

Comment: I also tried converting flat_model with torch.tensor first, which resulted in the same error

Comment: Not sure if it's error related, but don't you need `torch.cat()` to concat? [pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html)

Comment: Not sure either, torch.cat just came up when i searched whats the equalivant of .append() for Tensors.
Just to be clear, i want to append the object "list" to the flat_models list. e.g. have a 2dim flat_models_list where 1 axis is the models and 1 axis the params

Comment: try using `flat_models = torch.cat((flat_models, torch.tensor(flat_model)), dim=0)`